# Schema location of CI webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, peoplesoft

I'm new to Peoplesoft and trying to use existing CI web service "CI_CURRENCY". I've followed the steps mentioned [here](http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/component-interface-based-web-services):

This is how schema looks like in WSDL:

```
<wsdl:types>
 <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.ubs.com/enterprise/Tools/schemas/M615294.V1"  
   schemaLocation="M615294.V1.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.ubs.com/enterprise/Tools/schemas/M826465.V1"  
   schemaLocation="M826465.V1.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.ubs.com/enterprise/Tools/schemas/M929890.V1" 
   schemaLocation="M929890.V1.xsd"/>
```

Now, I want to generate stubs from this WSDL file. For that I'm using apache axis. I've saved this wsdl into my local drive and executing below command - 
       java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -o src -p com.test.generated -s Currency.wsdl

But I'm getting error saying that schema not found as it is trying to find schema within the drive where wsdl is locatd. 
My question is how do I get all schema refered in generated wsdl or is there any other way to generate stubs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download xsd schema on

PeopleTools > Integration Broker > Integration Setup > Messages , schema is on "Schema" page

or

You can connect wsdl link via [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).
Then, you can download xsd file from that tool.